# Different javascript files for different browsers

Tags: javascript, browser-detection

I would like to have two separated Javascript files. One for IE and another one for all other browsers. How would I do that?

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ie.js"></script>
<![endif]-->


<!--[if ALL OTHER BROWSERS THAN IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/all.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: take a look at `jQuery.getScript()`

Comment: You got it! Good idea, too, imo.

Comment: @Tom Gullen: Because MSIE < 9 is horribly broken in regards to standards compliance, and nobody uses 9 yet?

Comment: @Jho, Jquery does all the standard compliance stuff for you, wouldn't it be easier to use that?

Comment: @Tom Gullen: Well, maybe he wants to create a site that goes all bonkers on IE, to discourage its use? ;)  Or maybe ie.js has Javascript stuff to fix some other working-but-not-in-IE functionality on the site? Or when developing new features to a web app, you don't want to expose the functionality to a browser that you haven't tested it on yet... Especially when the browser isn't best known for following the standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ie.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/all.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks. That works great. Is this the best (most optimized) way to do it?

Comment: @Hakan: I don't know if you can "optimize" two HTML statements much... ;)  But yes, it's valid (X)HTML, works as you described and doesn't depend on anything to be turned on or off in the browser, so it's certainly the most universal one.

Comment: He he thanks. This is probably the best way of doing it. Glad it was valid (X)HTML... Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getScript("js/" + ($.browser.msie ? "ie.js" : "all.js"));
```

That should be all you need to do.